# Osclass 3.2.1 directs me not to the index page

Tags: php, osclass

I am using Osclass 3.2.1 but when I visit my site it takes me to this page 
http://housetostay.co.za/user/register yet it should take me to this 
http://housetostay.co.za . I have been trying to fix it and Google for answers but all I got did not work for me . Please any help will be appreciated 
Here is my  .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer the problem was Registered users only plugin when I disabled it all went back to normal